# php to json fetch folder and subfolder files

Tags: php, json

I am new to PHP, and am trying to write a script that fetches root folders and subfolders recursively and returns a JSON array. But with this code it only returns the files and does not display the root folder, subfolder and files.

What i have is this

```
<?php
  $files = array();

  $dir = opendir('/opt/');
  while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
      if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
      {
          continue;
      }

      $files[] = $file;
   }

   echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

Comment: that is actually the expected behaviour for your code. there is nothing related to folders or subforlders here

Comment: @LelioFaieta thank you for your response ,yes i know, so how do i add those functionalities